# Get FlatList to trigger onEndReached earlier

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-video, expo-av

I’m using `FlatList` to build a TikTok-style video player, i.e. one list item covers the entire screen.

I’m fetching metadata about 10 videos at a time from a REST API (via `useSWRInfinite`), then populating my `FlatList` and using `expo-av`’s `Video` component and Mux.com for playback.

Right now `onEndReached` is triggered when I get to video 10, and then the next 10 videos are loaded, etc. How can I change this so `onEndReached` is triggered already on video 9?

#### Code

```
// Fine-tuning video feed experience:
const VIDEO_FEED_ITEMS_TO_FETCH_API = 10
const VIDEO_FEED_ITEMS_TO_RENDER = VIDEO_FEED_ITEMS_TO_FETCH_API - 2

const VIDEO_FEED_FLATLIST_OPTIONS = {
  removeClippedSubviews: true, // views that are outside of the viewport are detached from the native view hierarchy
  windowSize: 3, // measurement unit where 1 is equivalent to your viewport height
  initialNumToRender: VIDEO_FEED_ITEMS_TO_RENDER, // number of items that would cover the screen for every device
  maxToRenderPerBatch: VIDEO_FEED_ITEMS_TO_RENDER, // the next chunk of items rendered on every scroll
  updateCellsBatchingPeriod: 100, // the time interval (ms) between each batch of items rendered
  onEndReachedThreshold: 0.001 // limit where next API fetch is triggered (% of viewport height)
}

<FlatList
  ref={flatList}
  data={videos}
  renderItem={renderItem}
  initialScrollIndex={videoToScrollToIndex}
  getItemLayout={getItemLayout}
  onScrollToIndexFailed={handleScrollFailed}
  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
  snapToInterval={viewAreaHeight}
  snapToAlignment='start'
  decelerationRate='fast'
  viewabilityConfig={VIEWABILITY_CONFIG}
  onViewableItemsChanged={handleViewableItemsChanged}
  onEndReached={handleEndReached}
  {...VIDEO_FEED_FLATLIST_OPTIONS}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onEndReachedThreshold` which you also used in your `VIDEO_FEED_FLATLIST_OPTIONS` object. For more information you can visit [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#onendreachedthreshold)

**Updated**

```
const VIDEO_FEED_FLATLIST_OPTIONS = {
  removeClippedSubviews: true, // views that are outside of the viewport are detached from the native view hierarchy
  windowSize: 3, // measurement unit where 1 is equivalent to your viewport height
  initialNumToRender: VIDEO_FEED_ITEMS_TO_RENDER, // number of items that would cover the screen for every device
  maxToRenderPerBatch: VIDEO_FEED_ITEMS_TO_RENDER, // the next chunk of items rendered on every scroll
  updateCellsBatchingPeriod: 100, // the time interval (ms) between each batch of items rendered
  onEndReachedThreshold: 1.5 // limit where next API fetch is triggered (% of viewport height)
}
```

Comment: Thank Yakup, what do you think is a suitable value here, so it’s triggered already on video 9? As you can see I’m using `0.001`.

Comment: It might depend on your design but try to use `0.5` or `0.6`

Comment: Design is: 1 list item = full screen height (TikTok style)

Comment: Updated your code and I tried sample project. If you want you can try it from [this link](https://codesandbox.io/embed/distracted-carson-ce1ckt?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark). Let me know if it helped!

Comment: Oh thanks Yakub! Can you tell me how you arrived at `onEndReachedThreshold={1.5}`?

Comment: Since you said that your design is in full screen height then 1 stands for the last item and while you are in the middle of the item that is before the last one it triggers `onEndReached`. So it makes `1.5`. Also, if it helps please tick answer for help others.